# Find position of joint from speed sensor

Tags: c++

I have a joint with speed encoder. I can measure the speed of the joint at any time. How can I extract the current position in C++?

I have idea in mind to find the area under the curve between two timestamps. Is this correct way to find the speed? Any other suggestion?

Comment: Seems like you made some mistakes in typing the above. Did you mistype "speed" for "position"? If you have a speed sensor, you'll never get an accurate position. If you have a position sensor, then you can easily measure position at known timestamps and compute speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to integrate the speed value in order to get the position. So your guess is correct.

But that value will be unreliable as integration may deviate by large quantities.

Encoders should be able to provide position data themselves (counts). See if you can get them somehow. That would be the best way according to me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right, I have information of position from the encoder. Actually I explained my problem in reverse way. Let's explain in other way. I have equations which measures the desired speed of the joint. How can I get the desired position from that speed value?

Comment: You need a control system. I'd suggest a simple PID control over velocity. If your joint works like a servo, then PID over position might be easier.

Comment: I was on vacations. My problem is still there. Let me explain my question again. I guess I could not express my question clearly. I am sensing all the joint positions and speeds of joints from the robot. Now I have formulated a new speed of contact angle of wheel with the surface. I want to know the absolute angle from the speed which is calculated. I have nothing to do with the controller.